# panacheentity streamall causes OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: quarkus, entitymanager, quarkus-panache

```
 try (Stream<Car> cars = Car.streamAll()) {
            cars.forEach(car->{
                saveCar(car);
            });
        }
```

problem is im streaming data with over 100k results and im getting

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

because of it

```
 try (Stream<Car> cars = Car.streamAll()) {
            cars.forEach(car->{
                saveCar(car);
                entityManager.detach(car);
            });
 }
```

this is what i have tried, but no result at all.. after like 90k results are processed it starts to slow down like for 1 processed entity per minute and then it throws outofmemoryerror

Comment: Use `StatelessSession` instead for iterating the whole db. And if you want to do a bulk update, it's better to use the `.update(..)` method.

Comment: You should profile your application to understand what object is filling your memory. In this case, I suggest you clear() the hibernate session, which includes the default 1st level cache. Do it from time to time... not for every entity.